# MVC3 with JsonFilterAttribute doesn't work anymore

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, filter

This code was working just fine before i moved to MVC3 ...

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("GetCommentListForServiceCall")]
    [UrlRoute(Path = "mobile/servicecalls/{id}/comments", Order=1)]
    [UrlRouteParameterConstraint(Name = "id", Regex = @"\d+")]
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "MobileCacheProfile")]
    [JsonFilter(JsonDataType = typeof(ServiceCallCommentNewDTO), Param = "comment")]
    public JsonNetResult CreateCommentForServiceCall(int id, ServiceCallCommentNewDTO comment)
    {
        ServiceCallComment entity = coreSvc.SaveServiceCallComment(id, 0, comment.CategoryId, comment.Comment);
        SetResponseCode(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        SetContentLocation(string.Format("mobile/servicecalls/{0}/comments/{1}", id.ToString(), entity.Id.ToString()));
        return new JsonNetResult(entity); ;
    }
```

here is the JSonFilterAttribute code

```
    public class JsonFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Param { get; set; }
    public Type JsonDataType { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            string inputContent;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
            {
                inputContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputContent, JsonDataType, new JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All});
            filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now The JsonFilter doesn't get the object anymore. It always return null ?

Is there something i have to do in MVC3 ?

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need this attribute as ASP.NET MVC 3 has [this functionality built-in](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2010/10/21/asp-net-mvc3-jsonvalueproviderfactory/).

Comment: Well i tried to comment the attribute but still i get a null object all the time. Do i have to include something else somewhere ?

Comment: The link is 404.  Is there an updated reference?  Maybe this one: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx